# "Мне было, чем гордиться" - запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то я окончательно запутался в запятых)) Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "чем" в предложении "мне было, чем гордиться"?
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

У Розенталя: Запятой не разделяются выражения типа есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чем подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, осталось на что жить и т.п., состоящие из глагола быть, найти (найтись), остаться и немногих других в форме единственного или множественного числа, вопросительно-относительного местоимения или наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т.п.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола.